Why is a program compiled with the same optimization features (AVX2, OpenMP) enabled much slower on Linux than on Windows?
Update2:
You can find the original codes below in the github link, if needed. You can also find the complete, exact changes I made to reproduce the problem, along with program logs. But they are in the edit history now (apparently including those details makes this question out of focus).
Update and highlight again: This is not a question regarding how to time a c++ program
Like I said in the original question, I specifically measured the real elapsed time (wall clock time), which is 20s (Windows) vs. 60s (Linux).  I confirmed this with a stopwatch on my phone. My only question is why this program, compiled with the same optimization features enabled, is much slower on Linux than on Windows?

I am trying to run this github code (hi this is a clickable link in case you didn’t notice) on Linux, but I find it runs 2x ~ 3x slower on Linux than on Windows. Using its official input example data/BS_1000_torus.xyz, on Windows it takes ~20s, but on Linux it takes ~60s (I confirmed this using a stopwatch on my phone). I am trying to figure out how to set up the compilation so that running on Linux matches the same performance. Let me explain in detail.
On Windows:
I followed the exact steps (enabling AVX2, fast floating-point and OpenMP) in README to compile the project with vcpkg and VS2022. Running the BS_1000_torus takes around 20s (confirmed with a stopwatch).
On Linux
On Linux, I made the following changes to enable the key features mentioned in README:

Removed the vcpkg toolchain specification in CMakeLists.txt
Added set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mavx2 -fopenmp -pthread -Ofast") to CMakeLists.txt, right after set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE) to enable the features mentioned in the README file.

Then I used cmake and make to compile it:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j

The output from cmake:
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- 3.3.9
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0")  
-- BOOST FOUNDED
-- Using header-only CGAL
-- Targeting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /usr/bin/c++ compiler.
-- Found GMP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so  
-- Found MPFR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so  
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.66")  
-- Boost include dirs: /usr/include
-- Boost libraries:    
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
-- Build type: RELEASE
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' -mavx2 -fopenmp -pthread -Ofast -O3 -DNDEBUG'
-- USING EXEFLAGS = ' '
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
-- Configuring done (1.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/3dlab/GCNO-master/build

Running with the same model as the Windows experiment above takes ~64s (confirmed by a stopwatch).
System specs:

Both tests are on the same computer (dual boot, not WSL), with Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz (10 cores, 2 threads per core). I set omp_set_num_threads(20); at the beginning of int main.
Windows system: Windows 10
Linux system: 5.15.0-88-generic #98~20.04.1-Ubuntu

Questions:

Why is the running time (actual elapsed time) so different (20s on Windows and 60s on Linux), even if I've enabled all optimization flags I can think of on Linux? Why compiling with the same enabled features (AVX2, OpenMP) leads to very different running time?
How can I set up the compilation so it is as fast on Linux as on Windows? Is there some optimization automatic for Windows but manual for Linux that I did not turn on?


you should measure the same code rather than doing several modifications to the code and assume it would have no impact on performance

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Without these modifications it simply won't compile. I've tried to make as few changes as possible. And correct me if I'm wrong, these modifications are merely made because some headers or functions do not exist on Linux, and should not lead to a program running 3x slower.

std::isinf should be fine on both, as well as int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and gamma_in_myrpd. Sure they wont affect runtime, but the lesser the list of modifications the easier it is to find the one difference that does affect runtime.

fwiw, the difference in #include<sys/io.h> and Eigen/... you can configure via include paths, then the code can be the same.

Can you try --ffast-math ? Also try adding -flto and increase the loop unrolling limit.

@AhmedAEK it is -ffast-masth, I also suggest using -O3 -Ofast -flto. Also compiler is fast moving thing in linux. Use newer version of gcc and clang if you can (your ubuntu 20.04 is so old, upgrade to ubtuntu 24.04), and use optimized version of openmp and other libs. I use Spack Package Manage for performance centric workloads,

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly You only have to give one optimization level (you have to choose whether it is -O3 or -Ofast), if you give two, it makes no sense. Which one should the compiler chose ? In that case, -O3 is obsolete because it is already included in -Ofast.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately I observe no obvious improvement with -ffast-masth -Ofast -flto. I will try a full system upgrade later

The question is about performance and timing ... but the behaviour in log seems  different.

Side note: why the condition OpenmpCnt % 1 == 0? It's always true.

@molbdnilo Typo, should be if (ii % 1000 == 0). The OpenmpCnt % 1 == 0 was there already in the repo, persumably once used for debugging purposes.

Use a profiler on the program, it should at least tell you where most of the time is spent. If you compare the profiles from both runs, it could give you a hint what's wrong.

Are you running a real Linux platform or a WSL (Linux, based on a Windows environment)?

@Dominique A real Linux system on a dual-boot computer

clock on Windows is non-standard and should not be used in cross-platform code. Use portable idiomatic C++ code to measure elapdsed time (scroll all the way down to see an example).

You should use OMP_NUM_THREADS=20 instead of manually modifying the program by adding omp_set_num_threads(20); which is not the standard way of doing that nor the recommanded one.

@JérômeRichard Thanks, but I am afraid this is what the original authors wrote, and it's not really my concern unless it causes the Linux program to run 3x slower.

Windows Time: 21.544, Linux Time: 1191.18.  My suspicion is that those two timing are using different units.  Making them not apples-to-apples comparable.

@Eljay Like I said in the question, I also measured Linux time with time too, which gives 1m4s, so the real elapsed time is ~20s (Windows) vs. ~60s (Linux). Even measuring both time with a stopwatch there is still a difference of 40s.

Lots of comments, so things seem to be of interest to some. Only the closing voters seem to be missing again... :-)

timing it with your phone means absolutely nothing. the only thing that matters is user time, not system time and not wall clock time.   Have you actually accounted for operating system scheduling and doing things you dont realize?  what else is going on on your machine during this time? we have no idea.   Are you isolating cores and using taskset so that your jobs are running unobstructed? You are doubling the number of threads compared to your number of CPU's do you have hyper threading turned on?

@UpAndAdam "the only thing that matters is user time, not system time and not wall clock time." Not really. A single-threaded program will have the same user time, or better, than a multi-threaded version, so should we just abandon multithreading?

Probably not so much a question about your code, which you have not included in any case, but more about the thread scheduling and core allocation of the respective operating systems.  Without the code, allowing anyone to reproduce your result I would say as it stands this is off topic and a superuser.com we question.

@Clifford I did include the code by providing a github link. I also described all exact changes I made for running the code. Well, apparently including all details makes my question “out of focus”, so that’s in the edit history now

@Clifford Anyway I also suspect it’s the OS rather than the codes. But how can I be sure? With a test program?

Your best tools for investigation are profilers (as @UlrichEckhardt mentioned) and example minimization (experimenting with changes to make the program simpler one step at a time, while still showing a significant difference in performance).

@ihdv that is a link to Master, not a tag.  It could change; you you might fix the problem, or delete the project for example, r wondering the question nonsense.  Off site links without supporting information never make for good SO questions which should be capable of standing alone without the external links being absolutely necessary.

@n.m.couldbeanAI thats not what I'm saying. I probably spoke too shortly i should have said first. Don't abandon multithreading or multiprocessing. measuring with a  stop watch is pointless if OS scheduler is involved. Unless he's using cpu_isolation and set_affinity to manually schedule where his tasks and threads are executed you can't show that the problem isn't schedule thrashing of other tasks unrelated to your program being scheduled in by the OS. if the user time is the same then it means you have some problem in your parallelization. focus on system time now, wall clock last

@UpAndAdam I don't need to show anything except wall clock times. 20 seconds good, 60 seconds bad. Where the problem is (bad compiler, bad OS scheduling,  bad planets conjugation, whatever) is the programmer's business to find out and eliminate. It is true that user time should be usually addressed first, but saying that wall clock time is not important is just wrong.

@UpAndAdam this program doesn't seem to have a problem with parallelization, since there are 20 cores and the wall clock time is roughly 1/20 of the total user time. So indeed one should concentrate on user time. I suggest profiling on both platforms, as others do.

Another way to eliminate unknowns would be compiling on Windows with gcc, and/or using WSL2. This could help pinpoint the culprit (compiler vs OS).

@n.m.couldbeanAI you are missing the point of why I'm saying starting at 'wall clocks' is bad. like i said i overstated it in that you shouldn't ignore it, but it shouldnt be your focal point beyond "bad".  We're off by 300% or 60% depending on how you look at it.  one translates to your very generous 1/20th which basically violates amdahl's law but assumes its perfectly linear but is a good lower bound for approximation, at 6.667 minutes total or the other is 20 minutes.  both can't be 1/20th here.  I'm saying there are factors in OS and scheduler with no control over them.

@n.m.couldbeanAI for example is Hyper Threading even turned on? How has the CGAL library been optimized and compiled for his Linux distro and processor? That matters, as it's likely doing quite a bit of the lifting here ( similarly with the openMPI package).  I would compile that myself with -march and -mtune flags as appropriate.  You have to compare apples to apples. I loved your idea of compiling on Windows with a GCC toolchain by the way. We have to eliminate unknowns and control things ( like the scheduler and other OS tasks ).  With the current gap there is something BIG we are missing

@n.m.couldbeanAI I would only say wall clock is unimportant to the general crowd of SO in the context that 99% of readers don't know what cpu_isolation is, and have not demonstrated the use of task_set/set_affinity, and removing the OS Scheduler from the equation for nearly all of the cores.  If you have done that then sure go ahead and look at wall clock time, but still take it with a grain of salt.  Profiling is next step here.  To measure performance you have to start from a proper foundation; what are you measuring? My view is biased since I'm hunting for micro's and nano's.
